# KCFinder - upload image to another server

Tags: php, file-upload, tinymce-4, kcfinder

I'm using KCFinder to upload images of my text field and i need save this images in another server. The directory where it is saved id automatcaly generated by de server where de img will be uploaded, but when i try to upload de img, i receive the "unknow error" error. My upload config is:

```
'uploadURL' => "http://server_ip/api_cms/uploads/kcfinder_".$_COOKIE['hash_UPLOADO2'],
'uploadDir' => "upload",
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In config.js specify this paramerter:

```
CKFinder.customConfig = function( config )
{
    config.connectorPath = "http://anotherserver/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php";
};
```

And you have to dublicate ckfinder to another server.